# How to call array elements in axios after promises complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, svg, axios

I am trying to get *font awesome* icons to draw in d3 by filling an array with axios calls to an api. I'm having an issue with the what i believe is the asynchronous nature of axios. When i log the array i get all of the elements to display although when i call a single element it returns undefined.

I think i saw a reason for calling console.log on the whole array works because console.log() is also asynchronous so when i call the whole array it waits until all elements are finished loading. Then when i call a single element it calls immediately. This is why i believe i can see elements when i call the whole array.

The main issue i have is getting my weathericons array elements to be defined when i make a call to an element in the .then function of the axios.all.

This is currently what i have...

```
axios.all(promises)
     .then(axios.spread((...args) => {
     for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
          weathericons[i] = args[i].data.fa;
     }
}))
// After everything is loaded from the server can we append our data
      .then(
          svg.append('svg:foreignObject') //d3 chart
          .data(options.labels)
          .attr('alt', "")
          .attr("height", xScale.bandwidth() > 100 ? 100 : xScale.bandwidth())
          .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth() > 100 ? 100 : xScale.bandwidth())
          .attr("transform", function(d, j) {
                    var height_adj = 60 * (xScale.bandwidth() > 1 ? 1 : xScale.bandwidth()) / 50;
                    return "translate(" + (xScale(options.labels[j]) + (xScale.bandwidth() / 2) - ((xScale.bandwidth() > 100 ? 100 : xScale.bandwidth()) / 2))
                        + "," + (yScale(0) - height_adj) + ") scale(" + (xScale.bandwidth() > 100 ? 100 : xScale.bandwidth()) / 50  + ")"
                })
           .append('i')
           .attr('class', function(d, j){
               return 'fa fa-' + weathericons[j] + '-o"'; //This is what i need to work
           })
       )
```

Im trying to have the weathericons array elements call for all the data so i get an icon with every data point. I just can't seem to figure out a good fix to this.

Is there a way to have the array fill completely before calling the .then statement?

Comment: Sorry the console.log isn't the main issue its actually the call to the weathericons array. I found the issue when logging it but when i call the array element it returns undefined. I just need to figure out how to get the element to be defined.

Comment: What is `svg` in the 2nd then()?

Comment: Its a d3 chart.

Comment: Change the 2nd `then( svg.append ... )` to `then( () => { svg.append ... })`. In fact, you don't even need the 2nd then() since you don't return a promise (or anything for that matter) from the first. The whole thing could be in the body of function which is the argument to the first then().

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thank you @marekful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely make the obvious mistake that the entire expression starting with `svg.append()` is the first argument to the 2nd `then()` but the argument to `then()` should be a function.

Change it like so

```
axios.all(promises)
.then(axios.spread((...args) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
         weathericons[i] = args[i].data.fa;
    }
}))
.then(() => {
    svg.append('svg:foreignObject')
    ...

})
```

But since you don't return a promise (or anything for that matter) from the first `then()`, the second is unnecessary. You could just write

```
axios.all(promises)
.then(axios.spread((...args) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
         weathericons[i] = args[i].data.fa;
    }

    svg.append ...
}))
```